# Algorithm to prune list of dictionaries

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of dictionaries `d` as follows:

```
d = [
    {"A": "ls", "B": "p", "C": "near a big lake"},
    {"A": "ls", "B": "p", "C": "lake"},
    {"A": "ls", "B": "p", "C": "near a lake"},
    {"A": "ls", "B": "q", "C": "fantastic"},
]
```

I am trying to simplify this list of dictionaries by removing the less verbose versions of the same triple. Triples are deemed the same if they follow the criteria:

- the values of key `B` match
- all words from the value of `C` for a given triple are fully contained within the value of `C` of the other triple.

Comment: ...and what have you tried so far? It doesn't look like you've tried to solve the problem yourself. See [ask] for more information on asking good questions.

Comment: `[t for t in d if not any(t != u and t["B"] == u["B"] and all(w in u["C"] for w in t["C"].split()) for u in d)]` -> `[{'A': 'ls', 'B': 'p', 'C': 'near a big lake'}, {'A': 'ls', 'B': 'q', 'C': 'fantastic'}]`

Comment: @SylvesterKruin If someone knows that they need an algorithm, and I know that they probably don't know the necessary data structure, I tend to think that the question is reasonable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried a two for loop approach but while removing I incurred in an index out of bounds. My current solution was something like: simplified_triples = []
curr_B = []
curr_C = []
for triple in d:
    if triple["B"] not in curr_Bs:
        simplified_triples.append(triple)
        curr_B.append(triple["B"])
        curr_C.append(triple["C"])
    elif any([triple["C"] in curr_C for curr_C in curr_Cs]):
        continue
    else:
        ...

Comment: What about the value of key "A" ? would you leave it to chance or did you mean to make it part of the distinctiveness ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody answered this, I will.

There is, of course, a naive solution.  Which goes something like this untested code.

```
def remove_duplicates(d):
    d2 = []
    for i in range(len(d)):
        found = False
        for j in range(len(d)):
            if i != j:
                if d[i]["B"] == d[j]["B"]:
                    if all_words_included(d[i]["C"], d[j]["C"]):
                        if len(d[i]["C"]) < len(d[j]["C"]) or i < j:
                            found = True
                            break
        if not found:
            d2.append(d[i])

def sentence_to_word_freq (s):
    dict = {}
    for word in s.split(" "):
        if word not in dict:
            dict[word] = 1
        else:
            dict[word] += 1
    return dict

def all_words_included (s1, s2):
   freq1 = sentence_to_word_freq(s1)
   freq2 = sentence_to_word_freq(s2)
   for word, freq in freq1.items():
       if word not in freq2 or freq2[word] < freq1[word]:
           return False
   return True
```

But that involves `O(n^2)` checks.  Is there a more efficient solution?

Well, yes, there is.  But it is a lot harder to code.  The basic idea is to create a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure and use that to search for matches without having to visit items 1 by 1.  There are a number of such approaches available, which are a lot more work.  They are not worthwhile unless you will run this many, many times with a lot of data.